# Delete a bucket in S3

Tags: .net, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am looking for a better way to delete an S3 Bucket.
AWS SDK for .Net does not allow to delete a non-empty bucket and
doesn't have any overloaded `DeleteBucket()` to delete any child objects in the bucket.

This is the way I am currently deleting a bucket -

- retrieve all the objects in bucket
- Delete objects
- Delete bucket

//Delete all objects in the bucket first - a non-empty bucket can't be deleted

```
using (ListObjectsResponse response = amazonS3Client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().WithBucketName(bucket.Name)))
{
    if (response.S3Objects.Count > 0)
    {
        List<KeyVersion> keys = response.S3Objects.Select(obj => new KeyVersion(obj.Key)).ToList();
        DeleteObjectsRequest deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucket.Name,
            Keys = keys
        };
        amazonS3Client.DeleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest);
    }
}

//Delete Bucket
DeleteBucketRequest request = new DeleteBucketRequest
{
    BucketName = bucket.Name
};
amazonS3Client.DeleteBucket(request);
```

Is any better way to delete a bucket in S3 - where I don't need to fetch the objects first.
Is there any method that I am missing in AWS SDK for .Net?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. Not even their REST API supports deleting a non-empty bucket:

> DELETE Bucket
>   Description
>   This implementation of the DELETE operation deletes the bucket named in the URI. All objects (including all object versions and Delete Markers) in the bucket must be deleted before the bucket itself can be deleted.

(taken from [S3 REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketDELETE.html)).

You are doing it the right way, by calling the delete multiple objects request. Just be aware that, if you are using versioned buckets, you must delete all objects in all of their versions before deleting the bucket.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still interested in this old question. And someone stumbles across it like I did. Especially someone that uses .Net core for S3 interaction.

In the meantime official **AWS S3 Utils** class emerged which has function called **DeleteS3BucketWithObjectsAsync** and supports deleting the bucket with all its objects. 
The official documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3UtilDeleteS3BucketWithObjectsAsyncIS3StringCancellationToken.html)

It is part of the AmazonS3Util namespace from the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to be the neat way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and got this error:  

Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception : There is no such thing as the ?versions sub-resource for a key
    ---- Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    -------- System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

i can connect with client and that bucket exists with objects. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to do it directly without the API.  There is a very easy way to delete a bucket in S3 using the "Lifecycle" settings using the **S3 Management Console**:

- Select the bucket you want to delete and go to "Lifecycle" under Properties.
- Add a new rule  Set the new rule to apply to the "Whole bucket"
- Click the "Configure Rule" button in the lower right
- In the "Action on Objects" pulldown, select "permanently delete"
- Set the number of days to "1"     You're done.  The bucket will be gone in 24 hours.